# Interchange rows in a matrix without using interchange operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm sure that it's already out there somewhere in the abyss that is page 37 on google, so I apologize. I haven't been able to find it.

Given some arbitrary matrix, how can two rows be interchanged using only a finite number of the other two elementary row operations (Adding multiple of one row to another and multiplying a row by some constant)?

Let's suppose our arbitrary matrix is the following
$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b & c \\
   d & e & f \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
What series of elementary row operations (excluding interchange) will result in the matrix
$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   d & e & f \\
   a & b & c \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: start by adding row $1$ to row $2$, then add $-1$ times row $2$ to row $1$....

Comment: Ah thank you. I wasn't sure how to start out. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The interchange operation can be written in terms of the other two elementary row operations. How can I conclude that "**interchanging two rows can be effected by elementary row operations of the other two types**" from this?

Answer (score 3):

For completion, you can do this in-place (that is, no extra storage):

As individual operations:

1. Set row 1 to row 1 plus row 2.
2. Set row 2 to row 2 subtracted from row 1.
3. Set row 1 to row 2 subtracted from row 1.

Comment: The interchange operation can be written in terms of the other two elementary row operations. How can I conclude that "**interchanging two rows can be effected by elementary row operations of the other two types**" from this?